# jQuery Mobile border on select text input

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have seen one very cool effect on this site: http://bit.ly/USeOuH

Here if you open it with some mobile phone (I have android) and if you select the input box, then there is no border coming, only the textbox is highlighted blue. When I create an input text box, then on my phone is coming one orange border, when I select the text box.

I have searched how to disable this, but found nothing. Is there some option, how to disable this orange border an make it like the site above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must edit JQM css file. Depending on a chosen theme (a - f, or more if you used theme generator find and edit border outline around selected items.

If remembered it correctly there is only one property per theme.

Got it, search css file and look for: .ui-btn-active, comment background and background-image, or change it to any color you prefer.

Also regarding your last posts you can find a lot of good stuff [here](http://appcropolis.com/blog/advanced-customization-jquery-mobile-buttons/). It will show you how to do a lot of customizations to JQM css.

Answer (score 2):

CSS [outline](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp) Property should be helpful for you