# Unusual behavior display while showing pop up screen in jquery mobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I am implementing pop up screen .But when i click a button My pop up is show .But when i click the field which is present on pop up screen .it show keyboad 
along with my background image .I didn't add any background image on that page .I only add background image on different pages but it is show in that page when i scroll the pop up screen

i don't provide my code because it too large.Can you please idea how it is possible .actualy i check on browser it is working fine problem is android device![image]

[image]

Comment: is there any way to send my code?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a image. Actually jQueryMobile adds a border to the active input field. You can change this via CSS. Please see the link [jQuery Mobile border on select text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546121/jquery-mobile-border-on-select-text-input)

Comment: i am not asking (brown  square).I am asking about background image.See difference in first and second background image

Answer (score 0):

It is not an image those lines are the lists that are created automatically for some reason you can check there will be some code for it in your code put it on git.

Comment: here is my code ..http://help.airbrake.io/discussions/github-issues/1034-code?unresolve=true

Comment: First download that code .Run index.html Then Press (+)Button from Header .it show pop up screen after that fill all field and press add button.It create a row in list view.

Comment: Click on row it show second page.Click header button again fill field press ok .it create row .Press row it show third page .click search button it show pop up here is the bug .you inspect move up and down you saw background image .But i didn't add ir